# Google Calendar sync in Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, calendar, google-sync

Has anyone got the [Google Calendar Sync](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=89955) to work on Windows 7 64-bit with Outlook 2007?

I have set up two way sync but it only seems to sync from my Gmail calendar to my Outlook calendar. If I make an appointment in my Outlook calendar, it doesn't show up in my Gmail calendar.

I tried running it as admin, but no joy. I also tried running it in compatibility mode (XP Service Pack 3). However it still gives me an error when I do a manual sync that says:

> Could not connect to Microsoft Outlook. error -2146959355

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Sync is not compatible with 64-bit system, as mentioned in [compatibility](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=98565)

> Compatibility
>
> Currently, Google Calendar Sync is only compatible with Microsoft
>   Outlook versions 2003 and 2007, and
>   operating systems Windows XP and
>   Windows Vista.
>         Windows XP 64-bit Edition is not compatible with Google Calendar Sync
>   at this time

Although they mention Windows XP 64-bit is not compatible, this probably holds good for successive 64-bit versions, for the time being.

An alternative might be [SyncMyCal](http://www.syncmycal.com/google_calendar_synchronization_64bit.htm)

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though google has made improvements because I just successfully installed google sync with Windows 7 64-bit and Outlook 2007.

Using 2-way sync, new outlook appointments made it to my google calendar.

Comment: Yep. It worked fine for me! Just installed it on 2010-09-04, and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Too late answer, but what you have to do to solve it is to repair your office/outlook install, and after that, everything should work. 
I'm using it in 7 x64 and works perfectly.

Comment: For information, there is no "too late answer", on these site. Think that people will find this question from search engines, so any good answer is welcome, even after the time the original asker went away.